# Rails uniqueness validation based on relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models...

```
  create_table "registrations", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "orientation_id"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "student_id"
...
  end
  create_table "orientations", :force => true do |t|
    t.date     "class_date"
    t.text     "class_time"
    t.integer  "seats"
    t.boolean  "active",     :default => true
    t.datetime "created_at",                   :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                   :null => false
  end
```

I want to create a validation in my registration model that says the student_id must be unique in each Orientation.

Comment: I guess this could work `validates_uniqueness_of :student_id, scope: :orientation_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly,you want the `scope` option of the `validates_uniqueness_of`.If so,this should work

In your `Registration` model,

```
Class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base

......

validates_uniqueness_of :student_id, scope: :orientation_id

end
```

And also,you should be generating a migration to add this

```
add_index :registration, [ :student_id, :orientation_id ], :unique => true
```

More Info **[here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of)**

Comment: That works Pavan, thanx! Also good looking out with the suggestion to add_index also.